# click event with stop and away issue in alpine js 3

Tags: alpine.js

[This is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGrw9.png)

i want to hide the 2nd Good Morning when i click on the first button Show Message that has x-on:click.stop vice versa

```
<div class="w-fit">
    <div x-data="{showMessage:false}" class="p-1 border space-y-1">
        <button x-on:click.stop="showMessage = true"class="p-1 px-2 rounded-lg bg-lime-500 text-white font-bold"> Show Message </button>
        <div x-show="showMessage" x-on:click.away="showMessage = false" class="p-1 mb-1 border">Good Morning</div>
    </div>

    <div x-data="{showMessage:false}" class="p-1 border space-y-1">
        <button x-on:click.stop="showMessage = true"class="p-1 px-2 rounded-lg bg-lime-500 text-white font-bold"> Show Message </button>
        <div x-show="showMessage" x-on:click.away="showMessage = false" class="p-1 mb-1 border">Good Morning</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

im using alpine js 3 in cdn

Comment: This is because `.away` (which has been deprecated, you should use `.outside` now) also listens to events. By using `.stop` you're preventing that. I'm not certain why you would want to use `.stop` anyway. There are many ways to achieve what you wish for, but a bit more context can help provide an adequate solution. For example, do you need a specific message underneath each button? Is it just 2 buttons, or scaleable?